# OSMF, Strobe media playback button over video

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, osmf

i want to use strobe media playback to show video and i want to create some  button and text at some part of video. Something like ads on YouTube.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @buda, sorry i voted to close your question, this is too broad, stack-overflow should be, I'm trying to do X I tried Y I ended up with Z, what have I done wrong?  Questions like I want to do XYZ how do I do it, are too open (unless you're simply looking for suggestions on libraries to use or something of that nature).  As is I would suggest you check out cue points http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjd_cVIbMR4

Comment: Ok, no problem, but i dont understand why question is to broad? I want to put overlay over video with OSMF and Strobe media playback?

Comment: Alright that's more narrowed than the original question, how it reads from the original question it sounds like you wanted someone to walk through setting up the text/button and cue points as well etc. if you're simply looking to overlay one on the other that's a succinct enough question, can you also clarify with your environment, is this Flash IDE or Flex/Flash Builder project, if Flex related which SDK version. (unfortunately it looks like I can't un-vote)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading the OSMF developer guide: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/OSMF/1.0/Dev/osmf_dev_guide.pdf

The Strobe team did a [advertisement demo](http://matbury.com/strobe/advertisement-demo.html?src=http://zeridemo-f.akamaihd.net/content/robinhood/robin_hood_25fps_3000-2.f4m&width=640&height=462&enableStageVideo=true&controlBarAutoHide=false&playButtonOverlay=true&showVideoInfoOverlayOnStartUp=true&plugin_ads=AdvertisementPlugin.swf&id=strobeMediaPlaybackId&ads_preroll=http://gcdn.2mdn.net/MotifFiles/html/1379578/PID_938961_1237818260000_women.flv&ads_postroll=http://gcdn.2mdn.net/MotifFiles/html/1379578/PID_938961_1237818260000_women.flv&ads_midroll=http://gcdn.2mdn.net/MotifFiles/html/1379578/PID_938961_1237818260000_women.flv&ads_midrollTime=20&ads_overlay=http://gcdn.2mdn.net/MotifFiles/html/1379578/PID_938961_1237818260000_women.flv&ads_overlayTime=25&autoPlay=true) a while back where they demonstrated the use of prerolls, postrolls and overlays.

Further explanation regarding the demo can be found [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/osmf/2011/03/stage-video-and-ad-insertion-plug-in-for-osmf.html).